# Error while running move_group.launch

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while I running move_group.launch for my arm I got the following error message. How can I fix this.

```
 etting /run_id to 3c1ae3dc-2d8b-11e3-a3d9-0c6076593c99
 process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3754]
 started core service [/rosout]
 process[move_group-2]: started with pid [3757]
 [ERROR] [1380956186.991328941]: Robot model not loaded
 [ERROR] [1380956187.032802851]: Planning scene not configured
 [move_group-2] process has finished cleanly
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87486/error-while-running-move_group.launch/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_group.launch makes the assumption that the robot description is already loaded on the parameter server. Look at demo.launch for example, to see how to include move_group.launch in your own launch file. You probably want to include planning_context.launch as well, such that the URDF is also loaded.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1